# How switch Columns into rows according to another key/ID columns in r?

Tags: sql, r, database, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a the following dataset :

```
> head(Dataset)

    IDCLIENT NUMDOSS PROV_200112 PROV_200212 PROV_200312  ....

      H44879 0104957           0           0           0  ....
     Z353025 0105289           0           0           0  ....
     B416771 0105309           0           0           0  ....  
       B5043 0105366           0           0           0  ....
     A725471 0105370           0           0           0  ....
    BE406627 0105371           0           0           0  ....
```

This a table of 125 columns and 250 000 obs

We have a table with two ID columns **ID1**, **ID2**  and the other columns register the values of a variables called Prov in a certain period of time from 2003 to 2017.

What I am trying to do is to transform this table so that I will have only 4 columns ( ID1, ID2, Date(or period) and Prov )  instead of 125 ones. Something like this :

```
>head(DF)
    IDClient      IDDossier     Date             Prov     
    B416771        0104957     PROV_200110         5    
    B416771        0104957     PROV_200111         0          
    B416771        0104957     PROV_200112        99  
    B416771        0104957     PROV_200212        1,23          
    H44879         0105289     PROV_200212       36,1
    Z353025        0105309     PROV_200312      10436,175
    BE4410         0105366     PROV_200406      10438,9
```

to do so I tried the following code, but it's really time consuming and I also got some errors/ warnings message from R:

```
# N= dim(ProvTab)[1]*dim(ProvTab)[2]
# DF=data.frame(IDClient=rep("",N),IDDossier=rep("",N),
          # Date=rep("",N), Prov=rep("",N), stringsAsFactors = F)
DF=NULL
periodd=as.data.frame(colnames(ProvTab))
start.time= Sys.time() # to count running time !
for (k in 3:ncol(ProvTab)) 
     {
  for (j in 1:nrow(ProvTab))
       {
  DF=rbind(DF,
           data.frame(IDClient=ProvTab[j,1], IDDossier=ProvTab[j,2],
                         Date = periodd[k,1] , Prov=ProvTab[j,k]))
       }
     }

end.time= Sys.time()
end.time- start.time
```

I really tried to look for other solutions but failed.

PS: R or SQL codes are welcomed !

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a pretty simple wide to long transformation. The `reshape2` package is great for this.

```
require(reshape2)

DF <- melt(Dataset, id.vars= c("IDCLIENT", "NUMDOSS"))

names(DF) <- c("IDClient", "IDDossier", "Date", "Prov")
```

If that's slow, you can try with `data.table` instead which is probably faster.

```
require(data.table) 
setDT(Dataset)

DF <- melt(Dataset, id.vars= c("IDCLIENT", "NUMDOSS"))
```

Comment: That's cool ! I saw the function melt before, but I couldn't understand it well. Thank you a lot !